# I want to save the axios.post request in a const and return that const in the function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

```
export async function getCategories() {
  const https = "xxxxxx";
  const url = `${https}/api/Category/GetCategories`;

  const userToken ="xxxxxxxx"

  const authStr = "Bearer ".concat(userToken);

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: authStr,
    },
    url: url,
  };

  const response = await axios(options)
    .then((response) => console.log(response.data[0].categoryName))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.toJSON()));

  const fetchedCategories = response.data[0];
  console.log(
    " ~ file: menu.js:27 ~ getCategories ~ fetchedCategories",
    fetchedCategories
  );

  return fetchedCategories;
```

when I
console.log(response) after setting
const FetchedCategories = response.data OR response.data[0].categoryId , since its an array I get this error in the terminal

WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 4):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using await and .then .catch at the same time. This won't allow you to catch errors using .catch. You need to use a try/catch block to handle the error. For example, you can re-write the function as follow:

```
...
try {
  const response = await axios(options)

  const fetchedCategories = response.data[0];
  return fetchedCategories;
  // or 
  return response.data[0];

} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
  // do something with the error
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

.then returns undefined,`.then((response) => console.log())`, so then the response returned at `const response = await axios(options)` is also undefined, a better approach is to use try/catch as suggested in the other answer

```
export async function getCategories() {
  const https = "xxxxxx";
  const url = `${https}/api/Category/GetCategories`;

  const userToken ="xxxxxxxx"

  const authStr = "Bearer ".concat(userToken);

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: authStr,
    },
    url: url,
  };

  const response = await axios(options)
    // this returns undefined (response) => console.log()
    //.then((response) => console.log(response.data[0].categoryName))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.toJSON()));

  const fetchedCategories = response.data[0];
  console.log(
    " ~ file: menu.js:27 ~ getCategories ~ fetchedCategories",
    fetchedCategories
  );

  return fetchedCategories;
```

Comment: Welcome @Zakaria, glad to be of help